# React Native Asynchronous calls inside loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-native

I have a following Component in a loop to be rendered in some kind of a slider with some place images. The PlaceExtraInfo Component is fetch (http request) some additional info about the each place (for the passed placeId) and is suppose to display it on the proper place slide:

```
return places.map((place, index) =>

   // there will be a fetch for each place id in the component
   <PlaceExtraInfo placeId={place.id} key={index} />
);
```

I am using Redux and in the PlaceExtraInfo componentWillMount I am calling the Action to do the fetch for each of locationId but I am stuck with the Asynchronous in loop trap (closure) as in all of my slides end up displaying the last http request response result.

I know I am suppose to pass some kind of index for each iteration but cant figure how to use it in this fetch iteration scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing the fetch out in this component and pass it down, something like this:

```
const placesInfo = await Promise.all(places.map(place =>
  fetch(url) //pass whatever you need from place into fetch
    .then((response) => <PlaceExtraInfo placeInfo={response} key={place.id} />)
)) 
//so now you will be making the api call and passing the info down to your component 
//and this will return an array of all the components
```